# .htaccess Mod Rewrite redirecting to 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I am trying to create seo friendly url but after wasting alot of hours i have come here to ask for help. I am using xampp for windows.

This is what I want to achieve:

http://localhost/article/100/my-article-title/

Where 100 is my unique article id stored in the database.

This is my .htaccess rewrite rule:

```
# Rewriting the article URL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(/)?$ articlepage.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

This is my php page url format:

```
articlepage.php?id=100&title=my-article-title
```

When I try testing the seo friendly url above I get a 404 not found error.

PS. I was also curious about something else, if I remove question title from the stackoverflow url and press enter with only url id it redirects back to the url with question title. How deos it do this?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]+` only allows characters, your "slug" `my-article-title` also contains dashes. Try changing to `[a-zA-Z\-]+`

Comment: @kerbholz Still no luck, Now I am getting the object not found error instead of it redirecting to my custom 404 error page

Comment: Does `articlepage.php` exist in your server root? Does `http://localhost/articlepage.php?id=100&title=my-article-title` work?

Comment: @kerbholz yes ofcourse it does exist

Comment: I have a lot of other settings done in .htaccess as well, they might be interfering with this one should I also share my complete contents of .htaccess file?

Comment: @Gingitsune What happens if you only have this much in your .htaccess?

Comment: @vivek_23 same object not found error even if I remove all the other content from my .htaccess file

Comment: @Gingitsune Just try `RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z\-]+)(/)?$ https://google.com [L]`. Just checking if the rule matches.

Comment: Do you happen to have a file/folder `article` in your server root? Could you maybe add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` (two lines) after `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: @kerbholz added it but still no luck ... and yes there is no article folder or file in root directory

Comment: @vivek_23 I did what you asked and it redirected me to google homepage

Comment: @Gingitsune In that case, the rule matches. Is all these inside article folder?

Comment: @vivek_23 nope all of this is inside root directory ... ok so instead of articlepage.php i tried "http://localhost/articlepage.php?id=$1&title=$2" and it worked .. Can you explain what really happened here?

Comment: @Gingitsune I think it wasn't catching the root domain correctly. Does adding a simple `/` like `/articlepage.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,P]` also work?

Comment: @vivek_23 No, it doesn't. I also thought that it should work but it wasn't but surprisingly enough the whole url works.

Comment: I know this won't help much in resolving the issue, but there should be no need to add the domain to the rewrite rule, once you deploy this to a live server it'll redirect to `http://localhost` - which is not what you want. That rule above is a valid and working rewrite rule and _should_ work unless you have some exotic settings in xampp (httpd.conf?) or somewhere else - or maybe there's a bug in xampp. (Can't test because Linux, where above code works just fine)